# Displaying Related records in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am trying to display child record's data in lightning and i am stuck with this.
I did go through this link but no luck there too : https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BRYdIAO
Everything looks fine from APEX perspective and in the comp's JS controller also i am getting proper data. Here is what i am trying to do.
Obj 1.Wine Cart obj and Obj 2. Wine Line Item ( **Lookup to wineCart object**).
In my doInit method i am doing the following.

```
<!--Name:  WineKartUserCartComp -->    
    <aura:attribute name="userEmailOnWineCart" type="String" default="chanz707@gmail.com"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.getCartDetails}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="wineCartItemList" type="Wine_Line_Item__c[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="wineCartItemList1" type="Wine_Line_Item__c[]" />

   <div class="slds-show slds-scrollable--y">
       <aura:iteration items="{!v.wineCartItemList}" var="wcl">
  Test >> {!wcl.Id} <== In this i am not getting anything
  Test >> {!wcl.Wine_Stock__r.Name__c} <== In this i am not getting anything
       </aura:iteration>
    </div>
```

In JS controller,

```
({
    getCartDetails : function(component, event, helper) {       
        var action = component.get("c.getcartdetailsOfuser");
        action.setParams({userEmailID : component.get("v.userEmailOnWineCart")});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state=response.getState();
            if(state =="SUCCESS"){
                var respObj = component.get("v.wineCartItemList");
                respObj.push(response.getReturnValue()); 
                var listItmsOfCart = component.get("v.wineCartItemList");
                console.log('listItmsOfCart 1>> '+JSON.stringify(listItmsOfCart));
                    for (var i = 0; i < listItmsOfCart.length; i++) {                        
                        console.log('listItmsOfCart 2>>'+ JSON.stringify(listItmsOfCart[i]));    
                        component.get("v.wineCartItemList1",JSON.stringify(listItmsOfCart[i]));
                        //Trying to push the same data in duplicate variable .but no luck here too
                    }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

And my Apex Controller:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Wine_Line_Item__c> getcartdetailsOfuser(String userEmailID){        
    return [select Id,Wine_Stock__r.Name__c,Wine_Stock__r.Bottled_Year__c,Quantity__c from Wine_Line_Item__c where Wine_Cart__r.User_Email__c ='chanz707@gmail.com'];
}
```

However i am getting expected result in my JS Controller ( this is from console,debug)

```
listItmsOfCart 1>> [[{"Id":"a1Q9000000JGKubEAH","Wine_Stock__c":"a1N9000000RbU6qEAF","Quantity__c":1,"Wine_Cart__c":"a1P9000000NQFmREAX","Wine_Stock__r":{"Name__c":"La Rioja Alta Rioja 904 Gran Reserva","Bottled_Year__c":2007,"Id":"a1N9000000RbU6qEAF"}}]]

listItmsOfCart 2>>[{"Id":"a1Q9000000JGKubEAH","Wine_Stock__c":"a1N9000000RbU6qEAF","Quantity__c":1,"Wine_Cart__c":"a1P9000000NQFmREAX","Wine_Stock__r":{"Name__c":"La Rioja Alta Rioja 904 Gran Reserva","Bottled_Year__c":2007,"Id":"a1N9000000RbU6qEAF"}}]
```

can someone please tell me what i am missing. When i do respObj.push(response.getReturnValue()); why the data isn't available on the component? Am i missing something or do i need to use renderers?
please suggest !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not so far from the right solution!

First, you're storing the current value of your `wineCartItemList` attribute in a Javascript variable.

Then, your Apex controller returns a list of `Wine_Line_Item__c` objects that you push in your newly created variable.

So, your right value is stored in a Javascript variable, but you need to update the lightning attribute if you want the view to be updated automatically with the right value.

Here's the missing code:

```
var respObj = component.get("v.wineCartItemList");
respObj.push(response.getReturnValue()); 
component.set("v.wineCartItemList", respObj); // this is updating the lightning attribute
```

Answer (score 1):

@Martin Thanks so much friend. !! However, I updated to code slightly for those who looking for an answer - How to show related record's data. the update is I am looping the through result and using Json.Stringify to set the each individual record data. here is the updated code.

```
({
    getCartDetails : function(component, event, helper) {       
        var action = component.get("c.getcartdetailsOfuser");
        action.setParams({userEmailID : component.get("v.userEmailOnWineCart")});
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state=response.getState();
            if(state =="SUCCESS"){
                var respObj = component.get("v.wineCartItemList");
                respObj.push(response.getReturnValue()); // You are pushing all the results to a variable
                var listItmsOfCart = component.get("v.wineCartItemList"); // get that variable data and loop through each element
                for (var i = 0; i < listItmsOfCart.length; i++) {
                    component.set("v.wineCartItemList", listItmsOfCart[i]);//now set each individual record details to variable
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```